# how to keep the background image height same throughout all page width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The background image width is 1579px, so beyond if we stretch the browser to say 1920px, the background image height changes, even though i have given a fixed div width(650px). 
So how can i keep the background height same throughout all page widths?

CSS:

```
.blue_bg1{    
    background: url("../images/hero-bg-espresso.jpg") no-repeat;
    height: 650px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just set a fixed/100% height :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cover` property.  Like so:

```
.blue_bg1 {
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It will change the background image height beyond its default width

Answer (score 0):

use `px` units in your `background-size` declaration:

```
.blue_bg1{    
    background: url("../images/hero-bg-espresso.jpg") no-repeat;
    height: 650px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 1579px auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

What about try to add some properties in background declaration?
Try this and return me if it helps you:

```
background: #0000FF url("../images/hero-bg-espresso.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
```

This is a shorthand property sets ll the background properties in one declaration.

See also:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Hope it helps.

Comment: It will change the background image height beyond its default width.

Comment: Interesting.
What about using:  "box-sizing: border-box;" ?

"The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include."

See this link about box-sizing property:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp